# Submenu in a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have a few inter-dependent combo boxes and, as new options come, new entries need to be added. I managed to reduce the number of entries by grouping certain family-like members, but now I need a new combobox, and it's getting cumbersome, plus it starts to look ugly. So I thought of adding a submenu. Currently, my way of populating the combo box(es) is through a `struct` with `enum` and `std::string`, something like this:

```
QComboBox *combo {new QComboBox(vbox)};
for(int i=0; i<struct.LIST_ALL; ++i)
    combo->insertItem(i, struct.names[i].c_str());
```

If I need to add a submenu at a certain position, how do I proceed? The documentation for `QComboBox` doesn't seem to have anything related to a submenu. Am I going the wrong way?

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684721/fill-qmenu-with-an-enum) answers my question.

Comment: Just to help understanding your question : you want to do with a QComboBox what you can do with a QMenu ?

Comment: @Scab Yes. I know it's not quite as orthodox, but it beats having too many comboboxes. I was actually thinking about making a QMenu inside a QComboBox, but when I tried doing it, it proved too much for me.