# Fill QMenu with an enum

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qmenu

I have a few `struct`s with `enum` and `std::string` and I used to fill `QComboBox`es with them using a `for()` loop. Something like this:

```
struct Struct
{
    enum Enum
    {
        ENTRY1,
        ENTRY2,
        ...
        ENTRY_ALL
    };
    std::string names[ENTRY_ALL] {...};
};
for(int i=0; i<Struct::ENTRY_ALL; ++i)
    comboBox->insertItem(i, names[i].c_str());
```

It worked, but given recent advances I need more entries, more `struct`s, more combo boxes, and it gets ugly, so I decided I'd switch to a `QMenu`.

Looking at the documentation and the examples, I see I have to provide a `connect()` for each entry, a `QAction` for each entry, etc, and if my `enum`s are large, this gets to be a problem, so I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process.

My question mainly comes from how come I only need one `connect()` for each `QComboBox`  and how do `QComboBox`es know that, if I fill them up, which entry does what?

---

If it helps, this is some bogus code, from here and there, of what I had:

```
// tank class, header:
class Class
{
private:
    // main entries
    struct MainStruct
    {
        enum Enum {MAIN1, MAIN2, MAIN3, MAIN_ALL};
        std::string names[MAIN_ALL] {"Main 1", "Main 2", "Main 3"};
    };
    // secondary entries
    struct SubStruct
    {
        enum Enum {SUB1, SUB2, SUB3, SUB_ALL};
        std::string names[SUB_ALL] {"Sub 1", "Sub 2", "Sub 3"};
    };
    // family of entries for SUB2
    struct FamStruct
    {
        enum Enum {FAM1, FAM2, FAM3, FAM_ALL};
        std::string names[FAM_ALL] {"Fam 1", "Fam 2", "Fam 3"};
    }
public:
    MainStruct mainEntries;
    SubStruct subEntries;
    FamStruct famEntries;
};

// inside the main window, there was a QComboBox doing this:
// header
QComboBox *cbMain, *cbSub, *cbFam;
// source
Class cls {Class()};
cbMain = new QComboBox; // same for cbSub, cbFam
// retranslateUi() (manually edited, not automatic), called each time the menu was clicked
void MainApp::retranslateUi()
{
    cbMain.clear();
    for(unsigned char i=0; i<cls.mainEntries.MAIN_ALL; ++i)
    {
        cbMain->insertItem(i, tr(cls.mainEntries.names[i].c_str()) );
        cbMain->setItemData(i, tr(cls.mainEntries.tooltips[i].c_str()), Qt::ToolTipRole);
    }
    // same for cbSub, cbFam
}
// a function that did what was supposed to do when a combo box entry was clicked
void MainApp::func() { /* execution with variables changed by the combo */ }
/* There were additional functions taking care of the rest.
 * Whenever an entry from the combo was clicked, somehow it "knew" that the entry was
 * changed and func(), when executed, it ran with the variables changed by combo.
 */
void MainApp::updateSub()
{
    switch(cbMain->currentIndex())
    {
    case cls.mainEntries.MAIN1: /*subentry stuff*/ break;
    case cls.mainEntries.MAIN2: /*subentry stuff*/ break;
    case cls.mainEntries.MAIN3: /*subentry stuff*/ break;
    }
}
void MainApp::updateFam()
{
    switch(cbSub->currentIndex())
    {
    case cls.subEntries.SUB1: /*fam entry stuff*/ break;
    case cls.subEntries.SUB2: /*fam entry stuff*/ break;
    case cls.subEntries.SUB3: /*fam entry stuff*/ break;
    }
}
/* The connect() were attached to specific combos. When an entry in cbMain was
 * clicked, cbSub and cbFam were properly updated and func() was run with
 * the proper values, when cbSub was clicked, cbFam was updated and func()
 * was run accordingly. Similar to an instant refresh.
 */
connect(cbMain, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(retranslateUi()));
connect(cbMain, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(updateSub()));
connect(cbMain, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(func()));
connect(cbSub, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(updateFam()));
connect(cbSub, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(func()));
connect(cbFam, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(func()));
```

Whenever I had to add new families of entries for the submenus, or even main menus with subentries, things would complicate, so I think a menu like this:

```
Menu:   Submenu:                AnotherSubmenu:
menu 1  submenu 1               altsub 1
menu 2  submenu 2 > family 1    altsub 2
menu 3  submenu 3   family 2    ...
                    family 3
```

would work better and unclutter things. The entries in `Menu` call the appropiate `Submenu`, which has its own `Family`, wherever they are, `Submenu` may call yet another level of `AnotherSubmenu`, etc.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to make the change from `QComboBox` to `Qmenu`?

Comment: I have a top combo box with main entries, each has a subentry in another c.b., then there are specialties with another c.b., but now, the subentries got additional subentries as a family of entries, and I need to keep adding c.b., it feels and looks awful. A menu will have the main entries as the menu, subentries with family of entries as sub- and sub-sub-menus.

Comment: Okay, I understand, you do not want to use many slots? And you want to get the object that emits the signal?

Comment: If all the entries would get their own slot, and `QAction`, and `connect()`, won't that slow down everything? Is there a way around it? Because each entry in each menu/submenu/etc will have to have its own action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect the triggered signal of all the `QAction` to a same slot and be able to have the object with `sender()`, and convert it to the `QAction` object type with `qobject_cast<>`.

Also if you want to use an index we could use the `setObjectName()` and `objectName()`

```
void {your Widget}::createAction()
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
    for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i){
        QAction *action = new QAction(QString("action %1").arg(i));
        action->setObjectName(QString("%1").arg(i));
        connect(action, &QAction::triggered, this, &{your Widget}::onTriggeredAction);
        menu->addAction(action);
    }
}

void {your Widget}::onTriggeredAction()
{
    QAction *obj = qobject_cast<QAction *>(sender());
    int index = obj->objectName().toInt();
    qDebug()<<index;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Is there a way to convert `QObject *` to an `int`, or something more palpable? The way a `QComboBox` sends an integer when an entry is clicked? I've also modified the question with some bogus example, maybe it helps.